# Port Forwarding for RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, port, port-forwarding

I'm trying to setup Remote Desktop on my computer. It's currently running Windows 7. RDP is set to allow for incoming connections.

I've followed the instructions at PortForward.com, but am having no luck. Here's the details:

```
Router: TP-LINK WR841N -- WanIP=192.168.0.2, LanIP=192.168.0.1
                          DHCP Bounds = 192.168.1.100 (start) through 192.168.1.199

Computer Static IP (Assigned) = 192.168.1.151

External IP (whatsmyip.com) = 111.67.xxx.xxx
```

Also of note, I have port 3389 forwarded on the router to IP 192.168.1.151 and it is enabled for all protocols.

Now when I run PFPortCheck, I get "Could not test port 3389 because some other application has that port locked. Please close any applications that may be using this port and try again."

Now this is funny, as I have removed all antivirus and firewall software from my computer, and disabled Windows Defender.

So, I run "netstat -aon" and I get the following:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:3389    0.0.0.0.:0    LISTENING    PID=1216
```

PID 1216 doesn't show in Task Manager, but using "tasklist" from the command line reveals that it's svchost.exe. So I killed the process with "taskkill /PID 1216 /F" and it magically terminated.

Returning back to PFPortCheck, I try to test the port again. Only now I get "We were unable to ping your router" and "Your port is NOT OPEN or not reachable!".

So, can anyone tell me how I can open this port so I can walk accross the street and RDP into it?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Can you connect locally? Like from another computer in your LAN?

Comment: What is the subnet mask for your WAN, and what is the subnet mask for your LAN?

Comment: WAN subnet = 255.255.255.0  /  LAN subnet = 255.255.255.0

Comment: Haven't had any luck connecting locally either, really not even sure how to try

Comment: A)You must succeed in connecting locally before considering the router.  B)Your network's IPS are both overly complex, and the subnet masks don't match them either.  A way of fixing your IPS, is make your computer's static ip  192.168.0.zzz   And your DHCP 192.168.0.aaa to 192.168.0.bbb  (where aaa is less than bbb). Then your subnet mask can be 255.255.255.0   At the moment given your LAN IP, Computer's IP, and LAN subnet mask, your computer's IP is not on your network so you'll have problems.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Once you get your LAN IPs sorted out, then try connecting a laptop to your LAN, then you try to connect to the other computer on your LAN with RDP.

Comment: @barlop - I tried changing the DHCP start & end to 192.168.0.aaa to 192.168.0.bbb with a default gateway of 192.168.0.1, after making my computer's ip dynamic. I got "The IP address is not in the same subnet with LAN IP address". So I tried changing ONLY the DHCP start & end (without modifying the default gateway) and got "Bad IP address pool (the Starting or Ending IP address)".  Not sure how to proceed here. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jason  when I wrote aaa and bbb,  I meant aaa and bbb are  NUMBERS. So you could make the DHCP range   192.168.0.10  to 192.168.0.50   All IP Addresses should start 192.168.0  And your subnet mask should be 255.255.255.0    all your IPs will be on the same subnet.

Comment: @barolp - yes, I know they are numbers (I'm a software developer, but nowhere near a networking pro). Tried the DHCP range 10-50, router subnet masks for both LAN/WAN are 255.255.255.0 (same for the computer), but I still get the same "Bad IP address pool" error as stated above.

Comment: @Jason OK use powers of two, with 192.168.0 So,   192.168.0.64-192.168.0.128   Subnet mask 255.255.255.0  See if that works. Then if that fails and only if that fails, Does it give "Bad IP address pool"?  Try putting your static IPs in that range. After you do that, does it say "Bad IP address pool"?   Report back

Comment: And in fact, if that fails too, then maybe your LAN and WAN have to be on a different subnet. So if the above fails too, then make it so WAN is 192.168.1.xxx and LAN is 192.168.0.xxx  subnet mask 255.255.255.0  as they were probably ok and something else is causing you not to be able to connect RDP within your LAN.

Comment: In addition, I suggest you install nmap and port scan the destination computer you want to view, from another computer in your LAN e.g.  nmap -P0 -p3389 192.168.0.151   While bearing in mind that netstat -aon run from and on the destination should show :3389 as it does in your paste.

Comment: @Barlop, thanks for the help. Have to reinstall Win7 (as well as everything else) at the moment, but will give that a run-through. Thanks again!

Comment: There is a lot that just doesn't make sense here. 192.168.0.1 on the LAN and 192.168.0.2 on the WAN, both have the same mask, so both are on the same subnet? They shouldn't be.  Next we have a machine on 192.168.1.151... I'm guessing you have it tied into the LAN, but since the LAN is x.x.0.1 and the machine is x.x.1.151 then they cannot talk to each other. (And BTW, DHCP is irrelevant here  since nobody is requesting an IP address.) Your WAN and LAN should NOT be on the same subnet..

Comment: @Larryc  indeed many things there don't make sense.. one of the things that seems odd to me an i'm not sure why i didn't remark on it in 2012, is where he wrote  `WanIP=192.168.0.2, LanIP=192.168.0.1`     Why would his WAN IP be a 192 address.. That's not a WAN IP!  (unless ,if memory serves.. it's possible for the ISP to give a local IP to a WAN interface.. which I might have seen long ago!)  I recently saw a case of CGN where I was give na public IP, but I think in the past I saw one where I was given a private IP. by my ISP. So maybe he is behind CGN and that is his public IP..

Comment: @Larryc either way.. he or a person with his situation should get local network RDP sorted out before any port forwarding. And i'm not sure how much he has thought about securing it either ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the process that's locking 3389 is RDP itself. If you disable remote connections first and test again it should be able to test successfully, at least that's how it worked for me.

1. Control Panel > System > Remote Connections
2. Disable remote connections and Apply.
3. Test again with port checker, could take a minute for RDP to release the port
4. After you have your results you can re-enable remote connections and Apply

This should at least narrow it down for you, currently I have the ports test successfully after disabling RDP. Not sure what the rest of the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP could be blocking *port forwarding* depending on your package.  The solution would be to upgrade your package. Ref: [Is my ISP blocking ports?](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2247234/isp-blocking-ports.html)
There are other work-arounds; ref: [How can I have a server even if my ISP blocks incoming requests to my IP?](https://superuser.com/questions/484602/how-can-i-have-a-server-even-if-my-isp-blocks-incoming-requests-to-my-ip)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that Windows Firewall is interfering.

Open the Windows Firewall MMC snap-in (`wf.msc` in either the run box or Start search box), click **Inbound Rules**, and find the following rules:
[image: windows firewall - inbound rules]

The group of 5 rules should be green-ticked. It's likely you don't need the TCP-WS-In/TCP-WSS-In rules, but I enable them anyway for completeness.

If they're not green-ticked, select all 5, right-click, then **Enable Rule**. Try to RDP in again.